# Alamofire POST Request

Tags: json, post, swift3, alamofire

I was hoping someone could explain what the POST request (with parameters) accomplishes.  When I run the following command, provided by Alamofire's documentation, this is what is produced:

Code

```
let url = "https://httpbin.org/post"
let parameters: Parameters = [
        "foo": "bar",
        "baz": ["a", 1],
        "qux": [
            "x": 1,
            "y": 2,
            "z": 3
        ]
    ]


Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in
    if((response.result.value) != nil) {
        let jsonVar: JSON = JSON(response.result.value!)
        print(jsonVar)
    }
}
```

Result

```
{
"files" : {

},
"origin" : "192.104.181.247",
"data" : "{\"baz\":[\"a\",1],\"qux\" {\"y\":2,\"x\":1,\"z\":3},\"foo\":\"bar\"}",
"headers" : {
"Accept" : "*\/*",
"Accept-Encoding" : "gzip;q=1.0, compress;q=0.5",
"Content-Type" : "application\/json",
"Host" : "httpbin.org",
"Content-Length" : "53",
"User-Agent" : "HTTPRequest\/1.0 (com.dexstrum.HTTPRequest; build:1; iOS 10.2.0) Alamofire\/4.3.0",
"Accept-Language" : "en;q=1.0"
},
"json" : {
"baz" : [
  "a",
  1
],
"foo" : "bar",
"qux" : {
  "x" : 1,
  "y" : 2,
  "z" : 3
}
},
"form" : {

},
"args" : {

},
"url" : "https:\/\/httpbin.org\/post"
}
```

What exactly is occurring with the parameters and the POST request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **url** you are hitting it allows a **post** request. You can get **json** response by **get** or **post** method. Usually you fetch data by **get** method and send data by **post** method. When sending data with **post** request it needs some **parameter** to satisfy its requirement , usually its predefined.

SO you are sending a **post** request here with **alamofire** and along with some **parameter** which satisfy its requirements. Here you are encoding the **parameter** as **JSONEncoding.default** which means it sends the **parameter** data encoded as **json** finally you get the response as **json** coz you declared **.responseJSON** . Hope that helps.

Comment: Yea that did help.  I realized that my parameters might be passed in wrong or constructed wrong.

Comment: I'm wondering why the parameters I created aren't being passed in correctly.  I have let parameters : Parameters = [ "x" : 2, "y" : 2 ], and this is my post code Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in
            if((response.result.value) != nil) {
                let jsonVar: JSON = JSON(response.result.value!)
                print(jsonVar)
            } else {
                print(response.result.value ?? "no response")
            }
        }

Comment: It is producing a no response result.

Comment: you sure the **url** you are hitting it accept **"x" : 2, "y" : 2** these parameters ?? If my answer help you than please accept the answer :)